# Parallel array copy in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm looking to copy an array into another in **parallel**, for example:

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int[] b = new int[a.length];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) // parallel
{
   b[i] = a[i];
}
```

In this example I would like one thread to copy the first 3 indexes, and another to copy the other 2. Of course it can be in any other variation as well.

---

Things to consider:

1. I am planning to run this on very large arrays so a small overhead is ok
2. There might be more code added to the loop body, for example another array - c which will get a[i]+1

---

What I have tried:

1. `IntStream.range`:

```
    IntStream.range(0, a.length).parallel().forEach(i -> {
        b[i] = a[i];
    });
```

This resulted in `Local variable percentiles defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final` error since `b` is not `final` and cannot be assigned.

2. fork/join: might be it, but looking for other solution which does not involve declaring a new class or extending the existing one.

Comment: How big are the arrays?

Comment: declare the array b[] as final and then assign the value to the array b in the respective position

Comment: https://ideone.com/vaP3pU <- it works even without `final`, YMMV - still, I see no real question here; if your compiler/runtime bitches about `b` not being `final`, just make it `final`, where's the actual issue? `Local variable percentiles defined in an enclosing scope` suggests you have a variable called `percentiles` somewhere, and it looks like the real source of the error.

Comment: @malt the arrays have over 100,000,000 elements. I understand that it might be quicker to do it sequencial but wanted to know if it is possible to make it parallel

Comment: @Bishal Jaiswal I was sure you couldn't do it! it might solve attempt number 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to do this in parallel; because you're working with an `int[]`, you can use `clone()` to copy it:

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int[] b = a.clone();
```

If, for some reason, you still want to do this in parallel, then you can use [`Arrays#parallelSetAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)):

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(b, i -> a[i]);
```

For each snippet, the elements of `b` are equivalent:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Nice solution. I wasn't aware of `Arrays.parallelSetAll`.

Comment: Seems you have **forgotten to meet also the Item 2**: *There might be more code added to the loop body, for example another array - c which will get a[i]+1* - **haven't you?**

Comment: @user3666197 In which case, OP can add `Arrays.parallelSetAll(c, i -> a[i] + 1);`

Comment: In which case the OP **will pay twice all the costs** of the add-on overhead costs of .parallelSetAll() + all the memory-I/O transfer costs to re-read all the a[i]-s again, won't she/he?